# unstructured data comparision using python or other etl tools

Tags: python, etl, data-analysis

I am collecting data related to electronic items from different vendors(from websites or apis), I need a way to find similar products from each vendor and link them in a primary database. For example: vendor 1 list a name as 'Samsung galaxy Note 4 ' and vendor 2 lists as 'galaxy note 4 black 16 GB' and vendor 3 as 'galaxy note 4', I need to link them all as single product and store the reference to different vendors. I did my search and found that this sort of analysis can be done using ETL's such as Talend and Kettle and used algorithms such as levenshtein, metaphone etc or FuzzyWuzzy using python. it worked for less than 50% of the data. my question is

1. what type of tool or package should i use to get the best results in this case?
2. no matter how good the tool or code, final decision about the correctness has to be made by human, is there an easier way to implement this mapping using GUI as final check. for example in python something like connecting to two tables and show that data in a ui(browser) and allowing user to drag and drop to the correct data.

I am looking for names of packages or tools to help me deal with the problem. 
I will really appreciate an anwser.

Comment: Tool recommendation is out of context for stack overflow. Though my suggestion would be `pandas`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already working with Talend there are components you can use to perform Fuzzy Matching on your data.
tFuzzyMatch is available for all users. tRecordMatching and tMatchGroup are available for Platform product customers.

First of all you can use tFuzzyMatch to compare a column from the main flow with a reference column from the lookup flow and to output the main flow data displaying the distance. Matching types include Levenshtein, Metaphone and Double Metaphone. You will find scenarios in the Talend Help Center around Levenshtein and Metaphone: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tFuzzyMatch

In addition, tFuzzyMatching and tRecordMatching (for Platform customers: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tRecordMatching ) are capable of matching data records between different data sources. tMatchGroup ( for Platform customers: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tMatchGroup ) can find similar data records in a single data source.

Comment: Talend Data that was help full thanks alot for your answer

Comment: Great glad I could have helped you!

Comment: tMatchGroup and tRecordMatching are available only in premium versions, is there any way to try these pallets?

Comment: Yes you can test with the 30-day trial version. Best.